# How to search for some text on a webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping

I have used WatIn before to scrape a lot of data off of websites. I know I could handle this task with that, but I am hoping for a much lighter solution if possible.

I want to be able to go to a URL, and see if the website has the word "open" on it, or if it has the word "closed" on it.

Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use html parsing.. [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) helps you for this.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the *right* way to go about searching for stuff in html documents :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use the [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) method and check the page with the [standard `string` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904283%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This is as simple as it gets.

If you want more, follow @mekici's tip: [The Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Answer (score 0):

Explore `HttpWebRequest` & `HttpWebResponse`. You can get the text of page in a string variable and use `IndexOf` or `Contains` to get the text